# How to pass an array of integers as a parameter from javascript to python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have a javascript code that obtains the value of several checked boxes and inserts their value (integers) into an array:

```
var my_list = $('.item:checked').map(function(){return $(this).attr('name');}).get();
```

I want to pass this javascript array to a python function as a paramter. This is how I am doing it right now, with ajax and jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "{{tg.url('/foo/bar')}}",
    data : {
            my_list: JSON.stringify(my_list),
        ...
    },
```

On the python side, I have this code, to get the parameters:

```
item_list = get_paramw(kw, 'my_list', unicode)
```

This works, but I am not receiving the array as an array of integers, but as a single string containing the "[", "]", "," and """ symbols, which I would have to parse and isn't the most elegant way of dealing with this whole situation I think.

How should it be done to receive a javascript array of integers as an array of integers in python (not as a string)?

Comment: I think that it **is** the most elegant way of dealing with that situation. The step you need is to parse the JSON in the python side: http://pymotw.com/2/json/

Comment: What framework/interface are you using to run this Python code? It might already have functionality to handle JSON built-in. If not… then it's just a call to `json.parse`, as acdcjunior suggests.

Comment: I am using the TurboGears 2.2.2 framework.

Comment: OK, I've never used TurboGears. You may want to look through the docs or ask around on a TurboGears forum to see if it has any JSON functionality. But meanwhile, I can write you a generic answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to send simple arbitrarily-structured data from Javascript to Python is JSON. You've already got the Javascript side of it, in that `JSON.stringify(my_list)`. All you need is the Python side. And it's one line of code:

```
item_list_json = get_paramw(kw, 'my_list', unicode)
item_list = json.loads(item_list_json)
```

If `item_list` in your JS code were the Javascript array of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `item_list` in your Python code would be the Python list of ints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

(Well, you also have to `import json` at the top of your script, so I guess it's two lines.)

Answer (score 1):

The *proper* way to send multiple values for one key is

```
data: {
    my_list: my_list,
},
traditional: true
...
```

Suppose `my_list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]`, this results a query string / POST data

```
my_list=1&my_list=2&my_list=3
```

Without the `traditional` flag, the result would be

```
my_list[]=1&my_list[]=2&my_list[]=3
```

Which of course works, but in TurboGears you need to access it as `my_list[]`.

On the other hand, I am not sure if the TG keyword argument passing work with multiple values; if you get a single value in kw, you can use `request.getall('foo')` to return all the `foo` keys as a list (possibly an empty list).